# Work in progress translation

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

What is the french translation of “a work in progress” in the context of a person being a work in progress? Is it “un travail en cours?”

Comment: It might help if you flesh out the English expression a little more. It seems a little vague to me. Does it mean "Don't expect me to be perfect", for instance?

Answer (score 3):

You could use something that doesn't literally translates as "work":

> Je me construis encore

or even:

> Je me cherche encore

**EDIT**

Those are expressions way more used than "travail" when talking about yourself. Because it's not a "travail" you're constructing, you're constructing yourself. Work is more global in english, you can use it for "a work of art" for example, whereas in french you would more say "une **oeuvre** d'art".

If you really want to have this "work" nuance, you could maybe say:

> Une oeuvre en réalisation.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound natural for me to say that I'm "un travail en cours" if I am talking about me being a work in progress. The closest I could think of in French would be to say that I'm working on myself, which would give:

> Je travaille sur moi-même.

If you would like to just translate "a work in progress" when referring to yourself, I would then just say "un travail sur moi-même."

Comment: I know, it’s a bit off to me too. So what would I use if I just want the phrase “a work in progress” referring to me? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this then: "je suis encore en train de me construire".

Comment: I would just translate it as "un travail sur moi-même" if you're talking about yourself, and "un travail sur soi-même" in general.