# "Work in progress" en français

Tags: anglais, usage, locutions, anglicismes, faux-amis

Je sais qu'il y a sur le présent sujet [une question déjà classée dans le FSE](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28465/work-in-progress-translation) mais je n'y trouve pas de réponse à mon problème.

Selon [linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/translation/work+in+progress.html) l'homologue de *work in progress* est *travail en cours*. Selon Google c'est *travaux en cours*. Y a-t-il des différences ? Quelle version est plus correcte ?

La locution *travail/travaux en cours* est-elle courante en français ? A-t-elle l'air d'un anglicisme ? Serait-on compris si l'on l'utilisait ? Avec quelles locutions plus francisées peut-on exprimer une idée voisine ?

Pourquoi ne peut-on pas utiliser *travail en/sous progrès* ou bien *travail en/sous progression* ?

Dans le [contexte général](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_in_progress) de l'expression, progress (anglais) et progrès/progression sont-ils des faux-amis ?

Comment: Une fois encore, tu t'interroges sur la traduction d'une locution mais ne fournis aucun contexte...

Comment: Eh bien, c'est à qui fournit une réponse de considérer le contexte le plus général ; on peut très bien être intéressé dans ce contexte ou même dans tous les contextes, du moins les plus courants (ils ne sont pas souvent en très grand nombre). On peut aussi se rappeler une expression hors de tout contexte et sans savoir l'associer à un contexte particulier.

Comment: @dimitris Que signifie « ce contexte avec le mot anglais » ?

Comment: @jlliagre J'a considèré la locution anglaise *work in progress* aussi connue que je n'avais pas besoin de donner un contexte particulier. Le commentaire de LPH explique bien mon raisonnement:-)! Désormais je donnerai toujours un contexte.

Comment: @LPH Je me suis demandé si progrès/progression sont des faux-amis avec progress lorsque progress est utilisé dans la locution work in progress.

Comment: @dimitris La locution anglaise est bien sûr connue et comprise. Ce n'est pas parce qu'une expression particulière est utilisable dans des contextes variés dans une langue donnée qu'il en sera de même dans les autres langues, d'où ma recommandation de préciser un ou plusieurs contextes.

Comment: D'autre part, je compte **huit** questions dans ta question. Elles sont certes liées mais la dernière : « *progress* et *progrès* sont-ils de faux amis ? »  aurait peut-être mérité d'être posée à part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exprimer *work in progress* en français dépend beaucoup du contexte. Je ne me souviens pas avoir rencontré *travail/travaux en cours* en dehors d'un milieu familier avec l'anglais.

Quand le travail est en cours depuis si longtemps que plus personne n'espère son aboutissement, des vieux sites web par exemple, je dirais plutôt *inachevé*.

Lorsque quelqu'un s'en occupe, on peut dire que le travail est *en chantier*. La progression est évaluée via *l'avancement* des travaux.

Ou alors, on tourne l'expression dans l'autre sens: par exemple, un artiste qui prépare un album musical peut dire que son œuvre est *en cours d'enregistrement*, ou pour un film: *en cours de tournage*, *en cours de montage*, ou plus généralement *en cours d'achèvement*.

Answer (score 2):

En complément de la bonne réponse de mouviciel, on **peut** utiliser *travail en progrès* dans certains contextes, par exemple en tant qu'appréciation du travail effectué par un élève en classe :

[image]
Source: [Tamporelle](https://www.tamporelle.com/tampon-maitresse-personnalise/3901-tampon-travail-en-progres-5-cm-a-personnaliser-tamporelle.html)

Le sens n'est cependant pas celui de *in progress* (en cours) mais indique une amélioration dans la qualité du travail fourni par l'élève.