# How would you phrase a "work in progress" in French?

Tags: sens, expressions, traduction, anglais, usage

I know this question has been answered multiple times already but I want to ask how to phrase this specifically in the context of referring to oneself as a work in progress. The best way I saw this phrased in the manner I'm looking for was "une oeuvre en realisation" (excuse the lack of accents) but I wanted to ask if this is a commonly used or accepted phrase? I like this because it also has the nuance of referring to a work of art.

Comment: Does this: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33918/work-in-progress-en-fran%c3%a7ais answer your question? (See the references therein as well.)

Answer (score 3):

Locuteur natif :

- Travail en cours
- Action en cours

Ou juste :
 " En cours " qui est beaucoup plus idiomatique  :

> "  Où en est cette livraison ? "
>
> " En cours "

On comprendra alors que livraison est en cours *d'acheminement*

Answer (score 0):

Une œuvre en cours... je dirais,